# Inserting an element into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I make an inset method that will add a number into the array in the correct order?

```
void addElement(int table[], int element, int length) {
    int x = 0;
    int temporary=0;
    cout<<length<<endl;

    if(length == 1) {
        table[0] = element;
    }
    else {
        if(length == 2) {
            if (table[0] > element) {
               int temp = table[0];
               table[0] = element;
               table[1] = temp;
            }
            else {
                table[1] = element;
            }
        }
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i< length && x == 0; i++) {
                if(element<table[i] && element>=table[i-1]) {
                    for(int y = i; y<length; y++) {
                        temporary = table[y+2];
                        int temp = table[y];
                        table[y] = element;
                        table[y+1] = table
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is as far as I have gotten. In my main class I have worked it out so that array is increased by 1. So there is one open space at the end of the array for everything to be pushed back by 1.

Comment: Seems like homework, and if so should be tagged as such. What is the input and output data?

Comment: can we rephrase that - are you asking for a insert function that will sort the array after an element is inserted?

Comment: I had wanted to just insert the element in the correct spot and then push the rest of the array back one

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand your question. Are you looking for a sorting function? (something that would order the contents of the array in ascending or descending order)

Comment: its ok haha. I am not even sure what I am looking for. I am basically just supposed to be able to add,delete, and display. When they are displayed they have to be in order without using a sorting method. tough right :-/?

Comment: You have a very peculiar indentation style. :)

Comment: I think the OP is inserting an element into an already sorted array. And I think this belongs to CodeReview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can scan the array from back to front, moving values up until you find the correct insertion point.

```
void addElement(int *table, int element, int length)
{
    int i = length - 1;
    for (; i > 0 && table[i-1] > element; --i)
    {
        table[i] = table[i-1];
    }
    table[i] = element;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If I could give you more points I would. You helped immensely. The code that I had written out was five times as long with issues all over the place. You Rock!

Comment: @Bill: Inserting into a sorted array isn't complicated but you do have to be careful about not straying outside the array bounds and the case of an empty array.

Comment: This is not looking very efficient!

Comment: @Bernard: The options are limited when inserting into an _array of contiguous elements_. Every existing value greater than the new value must be shifted over to make room. This performs the minimum number of moves and does it in-place.

Answer (score 4):

Write a shiftElements function, write a findIndexOfFirstGreaterThan function, then in addElement - find the index, if -1 then put in last slot, else shift elements using index, then a[index]=elem;

Answer (score 2):

Draw yourself an example, then work out a list of very simple steps required to do what you want.

Then write code that does those steps.

Comment: Your answer is based more on programming strategy than an actual solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: (Part of) the point of this homework question is to learn simple programming strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is what your looking for, but I think you want something that adds an element depending on its integer value. Also, I do not have access to a compiler at this moment so there might be a couple of errors. The code below is just written to give you a brief idea of what you could do, but probably not a perfect solution to your problem.

```
int addElement (int element, int array [], int length)
{   
    vector <int> vectorOfInts; //vector to store current order of ints
    vector <int> vectorOfArrangedInts; //vector to store arranged order

    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter ++) //loop to fill the array with values
    {
       vectorOfInts.push_back (array [counter]);
    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter < vectorOfInts.length(); counter ++) //loop through all elements 
    {  
       int temp = 0; //stores temp value of biggest number found at a specific moment
       int elementIndex; //stores indexes
       for (int counterTwo = 0; counterTwo < vectorOfInts.length(); counterTwo ++) //loop through all elements to find the biggest array
       {
          if (vectorOfInts.at (counterTwo) >= temp) //if value is bigger than current biggest number
          {
             temp = vectorOfInts.at (counterTwo); //change temp value
             elementIndex = counterTwo; //remember index
          }
       }
       vectorOfArrangedInts.push_back (vectorOfInts.at(elementIndex)); //add the biggest number to the arranged values
       vectorOfInts.erase (vectorOfInts.begin() + elementIndex); //remove the biggest element
    }
```